# Fan constantly running at full speed

Tags: linux, thinkpad, fan, sensors

*Here I am repeating a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166057/fan-constantly-running-at-full-speed) previously asked in a sister forum, as it is relevant here and I have neither received a response, nor been able to resolve the issue.*

On my ThinkPad T470 which is a dual boot with Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10, everything was working fine in Ubuntu until after a while I needed to boot Windows. Since then, the fan on the laptop runs constantly at full speed on Ubuntu.

I have tried the common solutions such as setting `acpi_osi=!Windows 2012` in the grub setting according to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/513578/502269) or setting fan speed using `thinkfan` according to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/402310/502269).

I have also checked my BIOS setting, but every thing looks normal as some options are set for *performance* and some set to be *balanced* between performance, energy consumption, and fan noise. The problem is Ubuntu seems to not recognize the BIOS settings or any other settings for that matter.

None of the solutions above made any difference in the fan noise.

Any help would be appreciated.

**GUESS**: I am suspicious about ACPI not doing its job for some reason.

**OBSERVATION 1**: One observation that may be worth mentioning is that the fan runs at normal/low speed when I boot the laptop and the grub menu prompts me to choose an operating system (Ubuntu or Windows) to continue with. Then the fan takes off to full speed as I choose Ubuntu. I think this means that BIOS settings work fine.

**OBSERVATION 2**: Trying to use fancontrol according to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/46135/502269), after running sudo pwmconfig, I get the following message:

```
hwmon3/pwm1_enable stuck to 2
Manual control mode not supported, skipping hwmon3/pwm1.
There are no usable PWM outputs.
```

**EDIT 1**: The power settings in Ubuntu doesn't seem to alter fan speed.

**EDIT 2**: Fan runs normally on Windows.

**EDIT 3**: The BIOS version on my machine is 1.59

Comment: Does ubuntu has some power performance setting? Are you always connected to the power outlet? Just guessing

Comment: *(Ubuntu or Windows)*. I guess that when running windows the problem desappears. I ask because can you be sure that't is not a hardware problem?

Comment: Is your BIOS version >= 1.43? See [n1quj25w.txt](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n1quj25w.txt): "UEFI: 1.43 / ECP: 1.29 Fix) Fixed an issue where fan might rotated with max speed due to not reading CPU temperature correctly."

Comment: @vfbsilva Thank you for your comment.  Ubuntu power settings doesn't seem to alter fan speed.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Thanks for the comment.  Yes, the fan runs normally in Windows.

Comment: @Freddy Thank you.  The BIOS version is indeed greater than 1.43

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are going to have to do some manual intervention to get ACPI working properly with your hardware

https://github.com/vmatare/thinkfan/

```
echo "options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf
```

Load the module like this.

```
$ su
# modprobe thinkpad_acpi
# cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
```

Then enable the module

```
Systemctl enable thinkfan
```

You will need to configure temp profile by editing the

```
/etc/thinkfan.conf
```

Examples are provided as `thinkfan.conf.simple`

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

> OBSERVATION 2: Trying to use fancontrol [...]
> `hwmon3/pwm1_enable stuck to 2`

I think I had this problem also. What worked for me, was reloading a `thinkpad_acpi` module with a script like this:

```
rmmod thinkpad_acpi
modprobe thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1        
echo 1 > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1_enable
systemctl restart fancontrol.service
```

Although it [has it's own problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/648311/unpredictable-hwmon-path-to-control-fan). Also, I couldn't figure out how to run the script automatically, when the problem with fans appear.